# Interactive rebase with Git Extensions

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-extensions

Did anyone managed to make an interactive rebase with Git Extensions ?

Option is available when rebasing, but whenever I selected the last n commits, select "interactive" in the rebase window, the editor pops up with "noop" comment instead of the commits lines.

Where am I wrong ?

Comment: working for me. in the "rebase on" have you put the SHA of the commit where you want to start the rebase?

Comment: Nope, I actually did not understood that the "rebase on" field was a free text box... My bad

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default, Git extensions sets the branch to rebase against to the branch you are currently working on. So, unless you change that, there is nothing to do and you get this 'noop' message. You have to rebase against something that is not your current HEAD. Either that is some number of commits back from your head (eg HEAD~4) or the origin's version of your branch (eg: origin/master) or a specific named commit.

Comment: Thanks for your answer patthoyts !

I did not understand how to give that HEAD~n option, I thought that the branch name option was a restricted select box.

I managed to do rebase without it by creating a branch on a previous commit, and choosing to interactively rebase on it, which is weird.

But the right way is definitively by freely entering the base commit with HEAD~n, just like with the command line.